# UML Class Diagram for MongoDB Collection

Tags: mongodb, graph, uml

I am trying to create an UML diagram for a graph in MongoDB.

I have tried

[image]

but I am afraid it is wrong, since both `source` and `target` in `Edge` should point to `Node`, so I guess it should have two arrows?

Also, I don't know what to write on the question marks.

A graph can have multiple nodes and edges, so the relationship from `Node` to `Graph` and `Edge` to `Graph` is one-to-many (i.e. there can only be one `Graph` associated to one `Node`/`Edge`). Also there can only be one `Node` associated with one `source` and one `Node` associated with one `target`.

Is it even correct to draw these UML Diagrams for MongoDB collections since they are non-relational databases?

Answer (score 0):

I would start modeling it this way:

[image]

So a graph consists of a number of nodes which are connected by edges. Edges are always between two (not necessarily different) nodes. In this way you can not individually model graphs that have different relations. If that is needed, you would need a different model here (probably you'd add an association between `Graph` and `Edge`). Alas, this shows how UML is used: starting a discussion and talk about the problem domain.

Now, how this is finally mapped to a database is completely irrelevant at this stage. You can map this to relational and non-relational DBs later.

Regarding the questions from your comment:

- The position of associations in a class diagram is irrelevant. They just need to end in the right elements.
- The `+source` and `+target` are role names. They are identical to properties of `Edge` with names `source` and `target` and type `Node`. The `+` is the scope public (`-` would be private; there are 2 more)
- The `1..*` means that the `Graph` has many relations to `Node`. It does not tell how this is realized. Could be an array later or other means of expressing multiplicity.
- Yes. The position of role and multiplicity is important. This is a drawback since UML tools place them automatically and they can eventually be placed badly with many connectors/narrow element spaces.

Comment: Thank you! I need the relation between graph and edge because of how my program is built. But I don't understand if the position of the lines are important: Should the lines from edge go from `source` and `target` or is it OK if they just hit the `Edge` box? What does it mean to say `+left` and `+right`? I presume `1..*` means '1 to many' (but does it say which has 1 and which has many? is it due to the position of the text closer to node than to graph?).

Comment: I just see that you named left/right source/target. I'll edit that as well.